# How to read status code from HTTP Post?

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers

I'am sending a POST request to a backend and try to read the status code, but I run in the following result: `status-code:0`

Here is my functions:

**Service:**

```
signIn(uname:string, pass:string): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Uname':uname,
        'Password':pass
    });
    let opt = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true  });
    let data = {};
    return this.http.post( url, data, opt )
    .map(res => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .catch( this.handleError );
}

private handleError(error:Response | any){
    let details = error.json();
    console.log('STATUS CODE: ' + error.status);
    return Observable.throw(details || error);
}
```

**Component:**

```
login(uname: string, pass: string) {
    this.user.signIn(uname, pass).subscribe(
        res => {},
        err => {
            console.log('ERR: ' + JSON.stringify(err)); 
            // returns {"isTrusted":true}
        }
    );
}
```

I want to be able to read the status code e.g. 404, 401 or 403 etc.
In my case I can see in Chrome console the status 404 - so I would like to display an errorMsg depending on status code error.

And when I switch in the console to: `Network` I get in the `Response` tab:

```
{"code":404,"reason":"Not Found","message":"Resource 'user/auth' not found"}
```

And if I output `error` in `handleError()`, I get:

`handleErrorObservable: {"_body":{"isTrusted":true},"status":0,"ok":false,"statusText":"", "headers":{},"type":3,"url":null}`

How can I reach this based on the posted code, or where is the mistake I'am running in?

Comment: Is your `hanldeError` method run as expected? If so, just `console.log(error)` and examine it to figure out how to extract the response code. It looks like what you need might be `error.code`

Comment: Sure... I already tried this. It returns: `Response with status: 0 for URL: null`
So, `error.code` would be in this case `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved.. it had really to do with the CORS issue. After fixing it, I was able to read the status code from in the Response.

The following article [Restricting access to a server using CORS](https://agnieszkatech.wordpress.com/2017/05/13/restricting-access-to-a-server-using-cors/) was really helpful.